# Prevent dictionary from modifications

Tags: c#, dictionary, pass-by-reference, readonly

How do I prevent dictionary items from modification outside of my class?
I have to expose collection of objects as a property, but then everyone can do everything with my objects. I tried to use `ReadOnlyDictionary` to wrap my public property, but `IntegerValue` property still can be modified from outside.

Sample code is below:

```
internal class MyRefClass
{
    public object ReferenceStrig;
    public int IntegerValue;

    public MyRefClass()
    {
     ReferenceStrig = "Initialized string";
        IntegerValue = 100;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var writableDict = new Dictionary<int, MyRefClass>();
        writableDict.Add(1,new MyRefClass());

        ReadOnlyDictionary<int, MyRefClass> dict = new ReadOnlyDictionary<int, MyRefClass>(writableDict);

    MyRefClass variable;
    dict.TryGetValue(1, out variable); #get an object from dictionary
    variable.IntegerValue = 0; #changing property of the object

    writableDict.TryGetValue(1, out variable); #get the same object once again
    #now property variable.IntegerValue == 0 instead of 100!
    }
}
```

Comment: that isn't the dictionary that is being modified. you need to make your `MyRefClass` smart about being readonly.

Comment: And what if I can not make it "smart" ?

Comment: you could wrap it in a facade.

Comment: For example, you can change your `MyRefClass` fields to properties with `{get; internal set}` modifiers.

Comment: And if MyRefClass contains more that one public field and these fields are objects with their own properties and fields? I don't think this is really possible to wrap every single class you have\use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class immutable, for example:

```
class MyImmutableRefClass
{
    public readonly object ReferenceStrig;
    public readonly int IntegerValue;

    public MyImmutableRefClass(): this("Initialized string", 100)
    {
    }

    public MyImmutableRefClass(string referenceStrig, int integerValue)
    {
        ReferenceStrig = referenceStrig;
        IntegerValue   = integerValue;
    }
}
```

This isn't really enough if ReferenceStrig is an object which itself isn't immutable. It works for this particular example because it can only be a string (which is itself immutable).
But if it was some other type, then *that* type would have to be immutable itself - and (recursively) any public fields and properties that it contains would also have to be immutable. (I call that "deep-immutable".)

Here's an interesting series of articles on immutability in C#:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you want to expose an object to "Client code" and yet you want the object not to be modified then you *must* return a "Immutable type". Either in the form of immutable class or an interface with only readonly properties.

This also means that all the properties and nested properties and so on of your type should also be "Immutable" otheriwse they will be still able to modify the nested members. In other words *All types in object graph of the type you expose must be Immutable.*

Another option is to clone the object and return the copy and forget about the modifications. But be sure you're doing a *Deep-Copy* and not *Shallow-Copy*. Shallow copy suffers from aforementioned problem.